# form is undefined in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, input

I have a form...

```
<form name="userForm" ng-submit="setUsers()">
  <input type="number" class="form-control" name="users" ng-model="users.num" required>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid">Continue</button>
</form>
```

And in my controller I want to see if the form is `$pristine`...

```
angular.module('myApp')

.controller('myController', ['$http', '$scope', function($http, $scope) {
  $scope.userForm = {};
  $scope.users = {};

  console.log($scope.userForm) //empty object
  console.log($scope.userForm.$pristine); // undefined
  console.log($scope.users); //empty object
  console.log($scope.users.num); //undefined

}]);
```

What am I doing incorrectly that I cannot get the form in my controller? I am using AngularJs 1.3

Thanks!

Comment: that means something is redefining your $scope

Comment: Maybe it's because you are setting them to empty objects in your controller. Have you tried commenting out those two lines?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access form because you are trying to do that before it exist. Please see code example below that can helps you.

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('fCtrl', function($scope){
  
 $scope.setForm = function (form) {
    $scope.userForm = form;     
    $scope.users = {};
 
   console.log($scope.userForm) //empty object
   console.log($scope.userForm.$pristine); // undefined
   console.log($scope.users); //empty object
   console.log($scope.users.num); //undefined
   
}
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="fCtrl">

    <form name="userForm" ng-submit="setUsers()">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="users" ng-model="users.num" required>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid">Continue</button>

      <span ng-init="setForm(userForm);"></span>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for the form to be available. If you access it after the controller has been loaded you will be able to gain access to it.

Test it quickly with something like:

```
 console.log($scope.userForm); // undefined

 $scope.logForm= function(){
    console.log($scope.userForm); // defined
 };
```

Open your console and see this bin http://jsbin.com/loqic/1/edit?js,output